# phpMyAdmin hangs on Laravel Homestaed

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, vagrant, homestead

I am using a [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead) together with Vagrant.

I want to use phpMyAdmin so I did the following:

1. Downloaded latest version at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
2. Unzip into www/homestead/phpMyAdmin
3. Added `192.168.10.10  phpmyadmin.test` to `hosts` file

And finally I added the following to `Homestead.yaml`:

```
folders: 
    - map: ~/www/homestead/phpMyAdmin # Path on my laptop
      to: /home/www/phpMyAdmin #Path of VM

sites:
    - map: phpmyadmin.test
      to: /home/www/phpMyAdmin
```

Although it works,every time after I boot my server with `vagrant up` and go to `phpMyAdmin` it will hang as soon as I click my first table. It looks like this:

[image]

When I click refresh everything looks fine

[image]

And from there on it works. Why is this happening, how may I fix it?

I have a Intel® Core™ i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz × 8 with GeForce GTX 1070, 32 GiB Memory on a SSD disk. So I can't image this is a hardware issue.

Comment: You must be using phpMyAdmin 5.0 ?

I will try to reproduce the issue, but can you open an issue on our tracker https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues ?

Comment: @WilliamDesportes whoups, thanks for the hint. I am acutally using 4.9.4, I try 5.0 and if the bug remains, I post an issue on the offical repository.

Comment: @WilliamDesportes nice it works with 5.0.1 !! You want to post this as an answer?

Comment: I posted the reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try version 5.0.1 or 4.9.4 of phpMyAdmin